# WebView will not load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, segue

I am new to Objective-C. So I have a table view that leads to a webView. Some how the WebView won't load. In my view controller for the webView I have

```
 NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.url
                                   stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

The TableView controller has

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

XYZToDoItem *tappedItem = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showArticle" sender:nil];

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showArticle"]) {
```

I think I am missing something under **prepareForSegue** but I don't know.

Comment: you mean it doesn't push to your webview controller?

Comment: I mean the webView is completely empty  and I connected it in the storyboard too. @CongTran

Comment: Can you set breakpoint in your webview controller, to see URL is nil or not, and does it call `[self.webView loadRequest:request];` method

Comment: some checks: make sure url is not nil, webview delegate is connected. iboutlet is connected.